# Determine what method is called by a function

Tags: matlab, function, bayesian-networks

I am working through the code in the [bayesnet toolbox](https://github.com/bayesnet/bnt), and I am struggling to see how I can tell which method is dispatched by a particular function call.

For example, the call

```
convert_to_pot(bnet.CPD{e}, pot_type, fam(:), evidence)
```

There are multiple `convert_to_pot` functions ([in folders here](https://github.com/bayesnet/bnt/tree/d905c537b8003ab1453a5617a1ad0d83b4de886b/BNT/CPDs)), for specific types of CPD, and so which is called, I think, is determined by some property of the object `bnet.CPD`. If the CPD node is discrete I think it calls `@discrete_CPD`, but is there a way to see for certain? or can you tell from the structure that results from the function call. Thanks

`methods(convert_to_pot)` returns *undefined*.

---

A worked example

```
    % set up graph and CPD's
    N = 4; 
    dag = zeros(N,N); 
    C = 1; S = 2; R = 3; W = 4;
    dag(C,[R S]) = 1; 
    dag(R,W) = 1;
    dag(S,W)=1;
    discrete_nodes = 1:N;
    node_sizes = 2*ones(1,N);
    bnet = mk_bnet(dag, node_sizes, 'discrete', discrete_nodes);
    bnet.CPD{C} = tabular_CPD(bnet, C, [0.5 0.5]);
    bnet.CPD{R} = tabular_CPD(bnet, R, [0.8 0.2 0.2 0.8]);
    bnet.CPD{S} = tabular_CPD(bnet, S, [0.5 0.9 0.5 0.1]);
    bnet.CPD{W} = tabular_CPD(bnet, W, [1 0.1 0.1 0.01 0 0.9 0.9 0.99]);

    %evidence node
    evidence = cell(1,N);
    evidence{W} = 2;    
    ns = bnet.node_sizes(:); [2 2 2 2]
    onodes = find(~isemptycell(evidence)); % 4
    hnodes = find(isemptycell(evidence)); % 1 2 3
    pot_type = determine_pot_type(bnet, onodes); % 'd'  :discrete
    fam = family(bnet.dag, 4); % 2 3 4
```

function call and result

```
    pot = convert_to_pot(bnet.CPD{4}, pot_type, fam(:), evidence)
%     discrete potential object
%     domain: [2 3 4]
%          T: [2x2 double]
%      sizes: [2 2 1]
```

---

Update from comments;

```
>> methods(bnet.CPD{e})

Methods for class tabular_CPD:

CPD_to_CPT              learn_params            maximize_params         update_ess              
bayes_update_params     log_marg_prob_node      reset_ess               update_ess_simple       
display                 log_nextcase_prob_node  set_fields              
get_field               log_prior               tabular_CPD             

>> class(bnet.CPD{e})

ans =

tabular_CPD

>> superclasses(bnet.CPD{4})

No class tabular_CPD.
```

But [`@tabular_CPD`](https://github.com/bayesnet/bnt/tree/d905c537b8003ab1453a5617a1ad0d83b4de886b/BNT/CPDs/%40tabular_CPD) does not have a `convert_to_pot` function.

Comment: Are you just referring to matlab overloading?

Comment: @zhqiat; yes, I think this is the sort of thing. But I can't see how the search path is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from the question (and I don't have this toolbox installed), but based on your description it sounds like bnet.CPD{e} is a class and the convert_to_pot is a class method for the various types of classes it could be.  In that case, perhaps you can try methods(bnet.CPD{e}) instead?

Comment: Hi CKT; I had tried `methods(bnet.CPD{e})`, and it does return a range of functions, but `convert_to_pot` is not among them. I had thought it could be the class of the argument that is used to call the relevant function. For the example above `class(bnet.CPD{e})` is `tabular_CPD`. But [`@tabular_CPD`](https://github.com/bayesnet/bnt/tree/d905c537b8003ab1453a5617a1ad0d83b4de886b/BNT/CPDs/%40tabular_CPD) does not have a `convert_to_pot` method.

Comment: Is it a subclass of another class?  If so, it might be its superclass that has the method.  You might also be able to use the "which(FUN1, 'IN', FUN2)" syntax to determine which method is being called:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html

Comment: Thanks CKT, I tried `which convert_to_pot in tabular_CPD` which leads to a `convert_to_pot` method. (I can also do this by right-clicking and opening the file). both of these approaches lead to the same function file, however, it is the wrong method. I don't think it has a super-class.

Comment: oh actually, [`tabular_CPD.m`](https://github.com/bayesnet/bnt/blob/d905c537b8003ab1453a5617a1ad0d83b4de886b/BNT/CPDs/%40tabular_CPD/tabular_CPD.m) had the line `CPD = class(CPD, 'tabular_CPD', discrete_CPD(0, []))` , which I think means it inherits the class of `discrete_CPD`, so that could be it. Although it doesnt show up in `class(bnet.CPD{e})`

Comment: You can view a list of classes that a given class instance inherits from with
    superclasses(bnet.CPD{e})
You'd want to use "superclasses" instead of "class" here, I think.

Comment: okay, thanks. That returns `No class tabular_CPD`. hmm I thought that was going to be it. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: One last thought based on the doc page for "which".  Does this work?which('convert_to_pot(bnet.CPD{4}, pot_type, fam(:), evidence)');

Comment: Thanks CKT, that does it indeed - apologies for skimming the doc... If you add that as your answer, ill happily accept.